# Tree view node tool tip disappears forever after first show / some seconds

Tags: winforms, powershell, treeview, tooltip

Have a simple tree view with nodes, my goal is to show a tool tip when mouse over the nodes.

The problem: the tool tip is not always visible, and if yes, it disappears forever after first show / some seconds. Didn't find any InitialDelay property for TreeViewToolTip

```
$Root1Node = $TreeView.Nodes.Add("Root1","test1")
[void]$TypicalConfTVnode.Nodes.Insert(0,"ChildRoot1","aaa")
[void]$TypicalConfTVnode.Nodes.Insert(1,"ChildRoot1","bbb")
$Root2Node = $TreeView.Nodes.Add("Root2","test2")[void]$TemplateTVnode.Nodes.Insert(0,"ChildRoot2","ccc")

$TreeView.ShowNodeTooltips = $true
$Root1Node.ToolTipText = "test1"
$Root2Node.ToolTipText = "test2"
```

The tree has images/icons, if it matters.

I had anothe idea, to set ToolTip on of the icons, but TreeView doesn't accept setting ToolTip. Have any ideas?

Comment: Please post [an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Option 1: Mouse over > tool tip appears > waiting until it disappears(tooltip default timeout) > mouse over gain > no tool tip

Comment: Option 2: Mouse over > tool tip appears > remove mouse, before default timeout > mouse over again > no tool tip

Comment: Seems to be one-time ToolTip use. I have other tool tips on TextBoxes or Labels, its not the same behavior.

Comment: I'm talking about the code you posted. Please put together the smallest possible sample that can be executed and show the issue you describe